# How to make a new column with counter of the number of times a word from a predefined list appears in a text column of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter, data-manipulation

I want to build a new column which contains the count of the number of times a word from ai_functional list occurs in a text column.

List given is:

```
> ai_functional = ["natural language
> processing","nlp","A I ","Aritificial intelligence", "stemming","lemmatization","lemmatization","information
> extraction","text mining","text analytics","data-mining"]
```

the result I want is as follows:

```
> text                                                                     counter
> 
> 1. More details  A I   Artificial Intelligence                             2
> 2. NLP works very well these days                                          1         
> 3. receiving information at the right time                                 1
```

The code i have been using is

```
def func(stringans):
  for x in ai_tech:
    count = stringans.count(x)
  
  return count

df['counter']=df['text'].apply(func)
```

Please can someone help me with this. I am really stuck because everytime i apply this i get result as 0 in the counter column

Comment: And what result do you have now ?

Comment: @azro I get zero whenever I run the function but when i checked in my text column it does give me some places where those words are present from the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do `count =` , you erase the previous value, you want to sum up the different counts

```
def func(stringans):
    count = 0
    for x in ai_tech:
        count += stringans.count(x)
    return count

# with sum and generator 
def func(stringans):
    return sum(stringans.count(x) for x in ai_tech)
```

Fixing some typos in `ai_tech` and setting all to `.lower()` gives `2,1,0` in the counter col, the last row has no value in common

```
import pandas as pd

ai_tech = ["natural language processing", "nlp", "A I ", "Artificial intelligence",
           "stemming", "lemmatization", "information extraction",
           "text mining", "text analytics", "data - mining"]

df = pd.DataFrame([["1. More details  A I   Artificial Intelligence"], ["2. NLP works very well these days"],
                   ["3. receiving information at the right time"]], columns=["text"])

def func(stringans):
    return sum(stringans.lower().count(x.lower()) for x in ai_tech)

df['counter'] = df['text'].apply(func)
print(df)

# ------------------
                                             text  counter
0  1. More details  A I   Artificial Intelligence        2
1               2. NLP works very well these days        1
2      3. receiving information at the right time        0
```